# Branch points of the Gauss Map

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $R$ be a compact Riemann surface of genus $g$ and $J(R)$ his Jacobian. For a subvariety $X$ of $J(R)$ of dimension $d$, denote the set of non-singular points of $X$ by $X_{reg}$. Consider thr Gauss map of $X$, 
$$G_{X}: X_{reg}\longrightarrow Grass(d,g). $$
What does it mean to say
$x\in X_{reg}$ is a singular point of $G$? Or yet, what does it mean to say $dG_{X}$ is degenerate in $x\in X_{reg}$?

How to observe that the set of images of these points, is the branch locus of $G$?

Thank you!